# An example of linear bounded but not injective operator

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

Let $T \in $
${\frak B}({\scr H}) \equiv
\{ A: {\scr H} \to {\scr H} \ \vert \ A $ linear continuous/bounded $
\}$

The operator $T - \lambda \mathbb I $, where $\lambda$ is one of
$T$'s eigenvalues, is linear, bounded but not injective.
Indeed, $\ker (T - \lambda \mathbb I) \equiv W_\lambda \ \cup \{0\}$, where $W_\lambda$ is the eigenspace associated to $\lambda$ (which is not void, if we assume $\lambda \neq 0$ exists).

**proof**. $T - \lambda \mathbb I$ is bounded:
$$
||T - \lambda \mathbb I|| :=
\underset {||\psi||=1}{\sup} ||(T - \lambda \mathbb I)\psi||
\leq
\underset {||\psi||=1}{\sup} ||T\psi|| + |\lambda| =: ||T|| + |\lambda|  < \infty
$$

---

Uhm... Is this even true?

Comment: Constant maps, right?

Comment: (Since you’re linear, the zero map.)

Comment: Yes, but ... aren’t constant maps injective?

Comment: They are the exact opposite of injective.

Comment: Yes, of course. Sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the dimension of $\mathscr{H}$ (a Hilbert space, I guess) is greater than zero, then the zero map $T\colon\mathscr{H}\to\mathscr{H}$ is obviously bounded and noninjective.

But you want to prove that specific example is a bounded noninjective linear map.

It is noninjective precisely by definition of eigenvalue. Now, for every $v\in\mathscr{H}$, we have
$$
\|Tv-\lambda v\|\le \|Tv\|+\|{-\lambda v}\|\le \|T\|\|v\|+|\lambda|\|v\|=(\|T\|+|\lambda|)\|v\|
$$
thereby proving that $T-\lambda\mathbb{I}$ is bounded and its norm satisfies
$$
\|T-\lambda\mathbb{I}\|\le\|T\|+|\lambda|
$$

Comment: Ok, but $T - \lambda \mathbb I$ is not necessarily the zero map, right? I was expected to show a non-trivial example...

Comment: @ric.san It is the zero map if and only if $Tv=\lambda v$, for every $v\in\mathscr{H}$. Which could be true, but not generally.

Comment: Ok, thanks. Lastly, can I be sure that at least one eigenvalue $\lambda \neq 0$ exists, $ \forall T \in {\frak B}(\scr H)$? I was assuming its existence, but I don't know if it's always the case...

Comment: @ric.san No, you can't, unless you're on *finite dimensional* Hilbert spaces over the complex numbers. If you have an infinite dimensional and separable one, with Hilbert basis $(e_n)_{n\ge0}$, there is a unique bounded linear map $T$ such that $T(e_n)=e_{n+1}$. This map has no eigenvalue.